# How to concatanate 35 columns at a time in pandas within a single dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Need to solve this using pandas if possible:

I have a large data frame (1000 columns and 100 rows) with each column containing either a 1 or 0.

I want to combine the values in the first 5 columns into a single column, then combine the following 5 values into a second column etc... until each column contains 5 values.

This needs to be done for each row also.

I have also tried solving this without using pandas, the output results in a string and contains \n at the end of each row.

```
z = pd.read_csv('number_file')
length = len(z) // 5 * 5
for i in range(0, length,5):
    (a[i:i + 5])
x = number_file[length:]
```

Input file (the numbers along the top refer to the columns)

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10...
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1...
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1...
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
```

Desired Output

```
 col1  col2 col3   col4  col5  col6
00000 10000 00010 00000 01000 00001
00000 10000 00010 00000 01000 00001
00010 00000 00000 00100 00000 00000
00100 00000 10000 00010 00000 00000
```

Answer (score 4):

#### `groupby` on `axis=1`

```
a = np.arange(df.shape[1]) // 5 + 1
df.astype(str).groupby(a, axis=1).agg(''.join).add_prefix('col')

    col1   col2   col3   col4   col5   col6
0  00000  10000  00010  00000  01000  00001
1  00000  10000  00010  00000  01000  00001
2  00010  00000  00000  00100  00000  00000
3  00100  00000  10000  00010  00000  00000
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some documentation to @piRSquared's good answer:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Reconstructing your dataframe with copy/pasta:

row1 = '0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'.split(' ')
row2 = '0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'.split(' ')
row3 = '0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'.split(' ')
row4 = '0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'.split(' ')

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(row) for row in [row1,row2,row3,row4])

# The idea is to create a categorical label "mask" with group labels (1 thru 6) to
# pass into the pandas groupby function next:

group_labels = np.arange(df.shape[1]) // 5 + 1  # Floor division, not a JS comment!
# We floor divide into 5 categories, but then add one to the whole array to be 1-indexed.

# So now group_labels is a list of integers, a sort of column-mask:
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]

# Now "group_labels" can guide pandas in grouping on columns (axis=1).
# agg(''.join) takes the grouped df and performs a string concat with no spaces.
# add_prefix('col') is fairly self-explanatory.
answer = df.groupby(group_labels, axis=1).agg(''.join).add_prefix('col')

# answer.values == 
#  [['00000', '10000', '00010', '00000', '01000', '00001'],
#   ['00000', '10000', '00010', '00000', '01000', '00001'],
#   ['00010', '00000', '00000', '00100', '00000', '00000'],
#   ['00100', '00000', '10000', '00010', '00000', '00000']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to try on numpy solution:

```
a = df.astype(str).values.reshape(df.shape[0],-1,5)
data = np.chararray.sum(a, axis=-1)

Out[1827]:
array([['00000', '10000', '00010', '00000', '01000', '00001'],
       ['00000', '10000', '00010', '00000', '01000', '00001'],
       ['00010', '00000', '00000', '00100', '00000', '00000'],
       ['00100', '00000', '10000', '00010', '00000', '00000']],
      dtype=object)


cols = ['col'+ str(i) for i in range(1, data.shape[1]+1)]    
pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

Out[1838]:
    col1   col2   col3   col4   col5   col6
0  00000  10000  00010  00000  01000  00001
1  00000  10000  00010  00000  01000  00001
2  00010  00000  00000  00100  00000  00000
3  00100  00000  10000  00010  00000  00000
```